# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python, django

I can not locate this error.
Error is genereted after I added one field in disease that is contact and taggable manager in models
If that is correct than is this error is generated due to Id field that I gave manually
Help  to me get out of this!!

- personal(myapp)/urls.py

  ```
  urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^.*doctorsu/$',  views.doctorsu.as_view(), name = 'doctorsu'),
      url(r'^.*disease/$',  views.AddDisease.as_view(), name = 'AddDisease'),
  ]
  ```
- mysite/urls.py

  ```
  urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^$',include('personal.urls')),
      url(r'^taggit/',include('taggit_selectize.urls')),
  ]
  ```
- models.py

  ```
  class DoctorSignup(models.Model):
      contact_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^[789]\d{9}$',message="Phone number must be start with 7,8 or 9")
      doid = models.AutoField(verbose_name='Doctor Id',primary_key=True,default=0)
      email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
      contact = models.CharField(validators=[contact_regex])

  class TaggedSymptoms(TaggedItemBase):
      content_object = models.ForeignKey("Disease")

  class TaggedMedicine(TaggedItemBase):
      content_object = models.ForeignKey("Disease")

  class Disease(models.Model):
      did = models.AutoField(verbose_name='Disease Id', primary_key=True,default=0)
      dName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      dtype = models.CharField(max_length=10)

      symptoms = TaggableManager(through=TaggedSymptoms)               
      symptoms.rel.related_name = "+"

      medi = TaggableManager(through=TaggedMedicine)
      medi.rel.related_name = "+"
  ```
- views.py

  ```
  class doctorsu(TemplateView):
      template_name = 'personal/doctorsu.html'

      def get(self, request):
          dsform = DoctorSignupForm()
          data = DoctorSignup.objects.all()          
          args = {'dsform': dsform,'data': data}
          return render(request,self.template_name,args)

      def post(self, request):                       
          dsform = DoctorSignupForm(request.POST)   
          if dsform.is_valid():
              dsform.save()                           
              cd = dsform.cleaned_data
              args = {'dsform': dsform , 'cd': cd}     
              return render(request,self.template_name,args)

          return render(request, 'personal/doctorsu.html')

  class AddDisease(TemplateView):
      template_name = 'personal/disease.html'

      def get(self, request):
          dform = DiseaseForm()
          ddata = Disease.objects.all()
          args = {'dform': dform,'ddata': ddata}
          return render(request,self.template_name,args)

      def post(self, request):                       
          dform = DiseaseForm(request.POST)          
          if dform.is_valid():
              dform.save()                           
              cd = dform.cleaned_data
              args = {'dform': dform , 'cd': cd}
          return render(request,self.template_name,args)
  ```
- forms.py

  ```
  class DoctorSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
      dname = forms.CharField()
      email = forms.EmailField()
      contact = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[789]\d{9}$',error_messages="Enter valid phone no.")
      class Meta:
          model = DoctorSignup
          fields = "__all__"

  class DiseaseForm(ModelForm):

      dName = forms.CharField(help_text="Enter disease")

      symptoms = TagField(help_text="Enter symptoms separated by comma")
      medicine = TagField()

      class Meta:
          model = Disease
          fields = "__all__"
  ```
- Traceback

  Traceback (most recent call last):

  ```
    File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
      execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
      utility.execute()

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 355, in execute
      self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
      self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 327, in execute
      self.check()

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
      include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
      return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
      new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
      return check_resolver(resolver)

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
      return check_method()

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
      for pattern in self.url_patterns:

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
      res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
      patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
      res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
      return import_module(self.urlconf_name)

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed

    File "E:\IT\project\program\20-8-17\mysite\mysite\urls.py", line 7, in <module>
      url(r'^$',include('personal.urls')),

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 50, in include
      urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed

    File "E:\IT\project\program\20-8-17\mysite\personal\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
      from . import views

    File "E:\IT\project\program\20-8-17\mysite\personal\views.py", line 3, in <module>
      from personal.forms import *
    File "E:\IT\project\program\20-8-17\mysite\personal\forms.py", line 50, in <module>
      class DoctorSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    File "E:\IT\project\program\20-8-17\mysite\personal\forms.py", line 90, in DoctorSignupForm
      contact = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[789]\d{9}$',error_messages="Enter valid phone no.")

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 517, in __init__
      super(RegexField, self).__init__(max_length, min_length, *args, **kwargs)

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 228, in __init__
      super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    File "C:\Users\Charmi Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py", line 122, in __init__
      messages.update(error_messages or {})

  ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
  ```

Comment: Include full traceback of the error  that you are seeing on the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error_messages` should be a dict, not a string.

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/models/).